# "Paradoxically my name can be the solution" - what am I?

Tags: riddle

- By definition I cannot exist, but paradoxically my name can be the solution
- You cannot solve me, but can conclude and resolve me
- You can try to figure me out, but you cannot figure me out

What am I?

---

EDIT:

Clue (the clue doesn't make it "easy" but much easier):

> If I have you eternally *riddled*, that is my specific intention

Comment: Just for clarification, I don't think this is too broad or too cryptic. The answer is entirely possible. I very carefully used words and clues that are relevant to the subject matter. They're not just random clues, they specifically point to the answer. Besides, do you want a riddle that is solved in 2 mins from first thoughts and guesses? Or from a bit of thought ;)

Comment: note that a paradox is supposed to be "A counterintuitive conclusion", but in every single riddle, the name of the thing we are trying to figure out _is_ the solution, so that isn't counterintuitive at all.

Comment: nope. only if the unsolvable riddle was the solution to itself would it be a paradox.  The unsolvable riddle is the solution to this (very solvable) riddle.

Comment: "*The unsolvable riddle is the solution to this (very solvable) riddle*" But it's an unresolvable riddle, so how can it be resolved?

Comment: ‍♂️ you still don't get it?

Comment: We could argue that "Ironically" or "coincidentally" could be a better fit here, or a paradox is more like "when an unsolvable riddle meets the riddler who can solve any riddle in the world".  But nonetheless people understand what *this* riddle is getting to and there's actually correct answer being provided.

Comment: *A barber shaves those who do not shave themselves, and does not shave those who do shave themselves. What happens when the barber shaves himself?*

Answer (score 45, accepted):

Shot in the dark, but are you

> An unsolvable riddle

By definition I cannot exist, but paradoxically my name can be the solution

> Riddles have solutions, even if they are difficult to piece together. However, an unsolvable riddle can be the solution to *this* riddle.

You cannot solve me, but can conclude and resolve me.

> An unsolvable riddle cannot, of course, be solved. However, you can conclude that you cannot solve the riddle, and therefore resolve the riddle.

You can try to figure me out, but you cannot figure me out.

> Naturally, you can try to figure out an unsolvable riddle. However, you cannot actually figure out an unsolvable riddle.

As for the clue:

> "If I have you eternally *riddled*, that is my specific intention"
>
>  Well, if you're stumped forever, then of course the riddle has been unsolvable.

Comment: *first* correct answer. Sorry I awarded this to Chaz as so many answers I was just getting to yours :)

Comment: Yay for shots in the dark! Great mind-bender, mate!

Comment: The solution may be that there is no solution.

Answer (score 21):

This also seems too obvious, but

> a paradox.

By definition I cannot exist, but paradoxically my name can be the solution

> Paradoxes can't exist, but they are named paradoxes

You cannot solve me, but can conclude and resolve me

> Paradoxes can be concluded impossible, and some can be resolved with extra restrictions. For example, [Russel's Paradox](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Russell%27s_paradox) can be resolved by naming n-th order sets.

You can try to figure me out, but you cannot figure me out

> You cannot reason out a paradox and come to a logical conclusion

Comment: That's not the answer nice try tho, it does work with the clues :) The actual answer is not that obvious though, will take some thinking - although that's hard to determine when one knows the answer

Comment: @James "although that's hard to determine when one knows the answer" that's a sign of a too broad/bad riddle.

Comment: I carefully thought about if it's too hard or not. It's difficult to get the sweet spot between being too hard and too easy, and knowing how well others might solve these things. Tho, I meant that middle ground can be hard to determine when you already know the answer, as you cannot have an impartial view

Comment: @james All three of the answers posted seem to fit alll the clues. You might want to try adding more clues before this becomes too broad.

Comment: It's not too hard, it just needs some thought. I'm new to this site, but I can't imagine it not being solvable in 5 mins = too broad :)

Comment: I don't think to broad means that it's to easy, to me it means that they are too much answers that would fit your clues so there are too many possibilities.

Comment: @James People aren't complaining about the difficulty of the riddle. They're complaining that it seems to have multiple solutions and, instead of the game being "Find an answer to this question", it's "Find the specific answer that I happened to be thinking of."

Comment: @James the problem with this one is "it's hard to determine when one knows the answer". Riddles usually have one answer that stands above the rest and fits much better. The clue made it better, and I think it's fine now :)

Comment: @James you deliberately left out the rest of my quote, don't put words in my mouth. "Riddles usually have one answer that stands above the rest and fits much better."

Comment: I didn't deliberately leave it out, I skim read and missed the 2nd bit, but you are right it was a bad quote. I skim read because we're debating problems with a Q&A that worked very well, everyone enjoyed, and in only 1 hour two people guessed within a minute of each other. I don't see a problem with that and we're just debating for the sake.

Comment: @James Perhaps I'm taking the wrong tone - I enjoyed the riddle, I'm just trying to give advice for your next one. The key to take away here is that riddles should have one clear answer. I believe that the clue made this riddle better and not broad. Good luck on your next puzzles, have fun on this site :)

Answer (score 14):

Is it:

> An unsolvable riddle

By definition I cannot exist, but paradoxically my name can be the solution

> There's no point in a riddle that can't be solved!

You cannot solve me, but can conclude and resolve me; you can try to figure me out, but you cannot figure me out

> You can't solve an unsolvable riddle

Comment: Cheers! Kendra beat me to it though!

Comment: My bad, so many answers I got to yours first :) so close!

Answer (score 8):

I am probably wrong, but are you:

> An imaginary number?

By definition I cannot exist, but paradoxically my name can be the solution

> The name "imaginary" sounds like it does not exist, yet it can be a solution to a problem.

You cannot solve me, but can conclude and resolve me

> You cannot solve it directly, but you can simplify it into -1 and use it to solve negative square roots.

You can try to figure me out, but you cannot figure me out

> You can try and figure it out, but you still do not know exactly what it is because it is an imaginary number.

Comment: Nope, but great attempt. And you are "closest" so far, sort of because of "imaginary". But that is still cryptic so don't take it literally :)

Answer (score 6):

Maybe a

> Logical contradiction?

Cannot exist in the real world, cannot be solved if it occurs, but you can deduce it (it concludes the deduction), and you can resolve it:

> To disprove a hypothesis, you need to assume it is true, and deduce a contradiction.

Figuring out the word as a solution is possible, but figuring out the thing itself is impossible, since

> If you start your deductions (figuring out)  with a contradiction in the premises, you can prove absolutely everything, and its negation too.

Comment: Nope, but great attempt.

Answer (score 6):

Are you

> Infinity?

By definition I cannot exist, but paradoxically my name can be the solution

> Many believe that it's an idea not being actual - however defining infinity means it can/does exist

You cannot solve me, but can conclude and resolve me

> You cannot count to infinity but you can define it.

You can try to figure me out, but you cannot figure me out

> I believe so

Comment: Was a good guess :) you were on the right track with the "impossible"

Answer (score 5):

My guess is

> A solution to this puzzle which is also not a solution to this puzzle.

By definition I cannot exist,

> This is a complete logical contradiction

but paradoxically my name can be the solution

> But this indeed may be the solution.

You cannot solve me, but can conclude and resolve me

> I don't think I can find a solution to this puzzle which is also not a solution but I can conclude and resolve with myself that this is the correct solution.

You can try to figure me out, but you cannot figure me out

> If I figure out a solution to this puzzle, I will have figured out something which is also not a solution so indeed, I haven't figured it out.

Answer (score 5):

This is a wild guess, but is the answer

> The largest Prime number...

---

By definition I cannot exist, but paradoxically my name can be the solution

> It is known that there exist infinite primes, if we somehow [find a pattern](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1698116/mathematicians-shocked-to-find-pattern-in-prime-numbers), many things will get easier.

---

You cannot solve me, but can conclude and resolve me

> We can not get the largest prime, but the search is still going on([GIMP](https://www.mersenne.org/)).

---

You can try to figure me out, but you cannot figure me out

> We can try to figure it out, but since it can get as big as possible, we can't get one(greatest) value.

Comment: Was a good guess :) you were on the right track with the "impossible"

Answer (score 1):

Are you

> a thought

By definition I cannot exist, but paradoxically my name can be the solution

> thoughts are somewhere in your mind, some searches say they are brain configurations, some articles say a thought has negative mass due to consuming energy to think.

You cannot solve me, but can conclude and resolve me

> we don't know much about thinking or thoughts, but everyone can think and have thoughts.

You can try to figure me out, but you cannot figure me out

> thinking about thoughts is confusing

Answer (score 1):

This works too, doesn't exist, you can resolve it or conclude it:

> Nothing.

Comment: Nothing is just a state of potential, imho.

Answer (score 1):

My guess is

> God
>  It is logically impossible for an omnipotent creature to exist.
>  The name can be used to solve things and answer the questions, for example, if you don't know something it means that God did it.
>  You can't solve something that can't exist, but you can imagine it exists and resolve it.
>  You can try to figure out, but God works in mysterious way so you can't figure it out.

Comment: Welcome to Puzzling.SE! Could you edit your answer to include spoiler tags, so as not to spoil your solution for anyone who wants to have a go at the puzzle themselves? Thanks!